# Exclude categories from homepage not longer working

Tags: categories, get-posts

I was using query for excluding categories from my homepage without problems until this week. I'd like to know the reason of the change and a better way to get this. I was trying also diverse solutions that I found here, no success.

```
function excludeCat($query) {
  if ( $query->is_home() ) {
    $query->set('cat', '-99, -263, -255, -268, -105');
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

I also tried this in the index. No results.

```
if ( is_home() ) {
query_posts( 'cat=-99, -263, -255, -268, -105' );
}
```

updated: [the loop in the index: homepage.php]

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => $homePortfolioShow ) ); 
rewind_posts();
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if(!get_post_format()) {
get_template_part('format', 'standard');
} else {
get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
}
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how this was ever working for you to begin with, but there's really no need to use a custom page template for the blog posts index template. WordPress provides a template file to use: `home.php`. Easiest solution:

1. Rename `homepage.php` as `home.php` and remove any custom template header comments
2. Remove all `query_posts()` references inside `home.php`
3. Ensure that Posts Page settings are correct in Settings -> Reading
4. Keep `pre_get_posts` filter in place

This will revert WordPress to using the reserved template, `home.php`, to render the blog posts index, while allowing WordPress to recognize the query as being the blog posts index.

Comment: There is another bug in his code, I guess. `pre_get_posts` is action and not filter.

Comment: ok, thank you guys very much. I'll try Chip's suggestion. And @KrzysiekDróżdż, you're right. I'll work on that. Thank you guys again

Comment: True enough, though, at their core, *actions* are really just *filters* themselves; so, technically, calling `add_filter()` probably works anyway.